# The Zohar on the Redemption

Tags: sources-mekorot, zohar, messianic-redemption

[Rabbi Zecharia Wallerstein](https://www.torahanytime.com/#/lectures?v=38333) (5:39) said that the Zohar in Shemos states the following:

*"In the beginning of the redemption, Klal Yisrael is going to go through many tzaros. Certain Jews will give up because of the tzaros. Most of the Jews will go off the derech. They will leave the rest of Klal Yisrael and join the enemies of Moshiach. Rabbi Shimon bar Yochai says, 'Woe to the person who lives in those days!' When Hashem comes to redeem the Shechinah from golus… He is going to look, in general to see, who is standing together with the Shechinah. He will into everybody’s deeds, but there’s not going to be that many tzaddikim.*

*In the times of Moshiach, whoever has emunah, he will see Moshiach. All the nations and their representatives, will get together and make sanctions against the Jews. They will write all types of edicts against us. They will all get together with one solution for the Jews…*

*The whole world will hide in caves and deep places. Then, the will be a great shaking in the whole world. Afterwards, Moshiach will come.*

*All the kings of the world will get together to fight Moshiach. Many Jews that left Judaism, will join the nations to fight against Moshiach.*

*In the times of Moshiach, the world will become dark like in Egypt for fifteen days. Many Jews will die in that darkness. However, because they died, that will be their forgiveness. Eventually, they will be resurrected. They won’t be like people that are thrown out.”*

Does anyone know where this is located in the Zohar?

Answer (score -1):

This material is not all in one place, but a good portion of what you're mentioning is in the discourse on the coming of Moshiach in Zohar, Shemot beginning at [7b, chapter 96](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14252&st=&pgnum=36) through [10a, chapter 156.](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14252&st=&pgnum=52)

[Page 7b, chapters 101 and 102](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14252&st=&pgnum=37) deal with the appearance of the [Shoemaker-Levy 9 comet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_Shoemaker%E2%80%93Levy_9) which broke into 21 pieces on July 7, 1992 (which corresponds to the 6th Tammuz, 5752, the day after the 2,424th anniversary of Yehoyachin, Melech of Yehudah being taken in chains to Bavel by Nevuchadnetzer) and its crashing into the planet Jupiter (Tzedek in Hebrew) starting on July 16, 1994. This spanned the week from the 9th of Av up to the 15th of Av, 5754.

[Page 8a, Chapter 112](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14252&st=&pgnum=40) through [page 8b, chapter 117](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14252&st=&pgnum=42) are dealing with the attack on the World Trade Center on September 11, 2001. That portion is supplemented by Zohar on parshat [Balak, 212b, chapter 501](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14246&st=&pgnum=667) through [chapter 507](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14246&st=&pgnum=669). Like it explains in the [commentary of the Sulam to chapter 111](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14252&st=&pgnum=40), this event is the beginning of the time of the final redemption.

Comment: @RealTorah - If you like an answer, consider marking it accepted.

Comment: Would you say that your statements about the comet and the terrorist attack are matters of interpretation?

Comment: -1 For presenting your own (dubious) interpretations as statements of the Zohar itself.

Comment: @ Yaacov Deane: Where in this link would it be found: http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/reader/reader.aspx?ocr=%25u05D9%25u05D3%25u05D9+%25u05E1%25u05D1%25u05DC+%25u05D4%25u05E6%25u05E8%25u05D5%25u05EA&sfid=53702

Comment: @RealTorah I'm not sure how to get rid of the thumbnail window, but it looks like Shemot 7b begins on page 29 of the link you provided.

Comment: @YaacovDeane: Here you go - http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/53702

Comment: @paquda There are many different ways to understand the text of the Zohar. But this particular section is dealing with the transition of Moshiach of galut to Moshiach of geulah. There are quite a few traditional commentaries to this section that explain exactly what I am saying. Rabbi Avraham Azulai is one, for example, who discusses this in his sefer Chesed l'Avraham, section Sod HaMikvah. There is a teaching brought in Sefer Tzaror HaMor quoting the Radak in parshat B'Shalach on the Chumash which underlines details of the Trade Center attack in connection with Shirat HaYam.

Comment: @RealTorah Yes, you can begin reading at the paragraph, Rabbi Shimon raised his hands..." on page 29. That is actually 7a, but sets the stage for the rest of the discourse.